# How can I separate words in td with an html tag?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

How can I use jQuery to separate multiple words in a `td` with an HTML tag such as `<br/>`?

For example, `<td>hello bye</td>` would become `<td>hello <br/> bye</td>`.

Comment: you can make stack overflow output text in a code style by putting ` around code, or by indenting each line by 4 spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work only if the HTML in the `td`'s does NOT contain any tags.

```
$("td").each(function(){
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(/ +/g,"<br/>");
});
```

Comment: this works if i replace it like this 

$("td.mytd").each(function(){ this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(" ","<br/>"); });

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery 1.4+ you could do this:

```
$('td').html(function(i,html){
 return html.replace(/\s/g, '<br>');
})
```

<s>The above doesn't appear to be working, where as changing the `.html` to `.text` works, but of course you can't add HTML elements that way. So your best bet would be to do this (change your TD Id's to TD classes):</s>

Edit #2 (replace the bad code)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('td.myTd').each(function(){
  $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/\s/g, '<br>') );
 })
})
```

But as Max Shawabkeh pointed out, this will cause problems if you have any HTML with attributes inside of the `<td>` (e.g. `<span class="text">...</span>`)

Comment: i tried this it dosent  work     $('td#mytd').html(function(){ 
 return $(this).html().replace(' ', '<br>'); 
})

Comment: Interesting... I didn't test it initially. It should work, but doesn't. I believe it to be a jQuery bug. To fix your problem, I think you should use a class instead of an id - I'll update my answer.

Comment: and an other problem is it duplicates it i use php what i have is this <td class="mytd"><?php echo $mon ?></td> <td class="mytd"><?php echo $thu ?></td> <td class="mytd"><?php echo $wed ?></td> is there any other way to accomplish this. it dont  have be  a html tag it could be dashes _______ i just wanna sparate it

Comment: Sorry, the code I added was bad, I have updated my answer with code I have tested.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("td").html($("td").html().replace(" ","<br/>"))
```

Comment: Two problems: 1. This will replace all `<td>`'s text with the text of the first one (plus replacements). 2. This will wreak havoc with html code inside the `<td>`s (inserting line breaks between attributes, etc.).

Comment: so for the ones that i want to use    <br/>   set id for it right??

Comment: so like this would work         $("td#mytd").html($("td#mytd").html().replace(" ","<br/>"));

Comment: @Max Shawabkeh: agree but the asker do not specified if it wanted all td or a specific one to be processed. And for the inner html elements he doesn't seem to have ones

Comment: @Gregoire: he did say *a* td, so maybe he's only interested in one specific td? random guess though and you may also be right :)

Comment: i ran into a problem here altough i used id  it duplicates all  cuz i use php it genrates tds <td id="mytd"><?php echo $data ?>/td>any idea

Comment: @jq-444 do you have an unique identifier for your data? So you can do the following: <td id="mytd<?php echo $youruniqueid?>"><?php echo $data ?>'/td> and acess it by $("#mytd<?php echo $youruniqueid?>")